# Output only shown when press enter

Tags: c++

This is the c++ code for a codeChef question    https://www.codechef.com/problems/UCL

input

```
 2
manutd 8 vs. 2 arsenal
lyon 1 vs. 2 manutd
fcbarca 0 vs. 0 lyon
fcbarca 5 vs. 1 arsenal
manutd 3 vs. 1 fcbarca
arsenal 6 vs. 0 lyon
arsenal 0 vs. 0 manutd
manutd 4 vs. 2 lyon
arsenal 2 vs. 2 fcbarca
lyon 0 vs. 3 fcbarca
lyon 1 vs. 0 arsenal
fcbarca 0 vs. 1 manutd
a 3 vs. 0 b
a 0 vs. 0 c
a 0 vs. 0 d
b 0 vs. 0 a
b 4 vs. 0 c
b 0 vs. 0 d
c 0 vs. 0 a
c 0 vs. 0 b
c 1 vs. 0 d
d 3 vs. 0 a
d 0 vs. 0 b
d 0 vs. 0 c
```

expected output

```
manutd fcbarca
d b
```

my output

```
manutd fcbarca


d b
```

Now the problem : It is that manutd fcbarca is outputting automatically but for d b .. I have to press enter twice which is creating two lines of whitespace...

query : How can i prevent it from happening I mean how can I get the second output same way as the first one(i.e, automatically - without pressing enter).

**MY code**

```
  while (tcs != 0) {
    matches = 12;
    while (matches > -1) {
      ifHome = "false" , ifAway = "false";
      int posHome, posAway;

      getline(cin, currentMatch);
      istringstream ss(currentMatch);
      ss >> home >> homeGoal >> vs >> awayGoal >> away;

      // cout << " " << home  << " "<< homeGoal << " " << awayGoal<< " " << away;

      homeGoalDiff = homeGoal - awayGoal;
      awayGoalDiff = awayGoal - homeGoal;

      posHome = searchHome(home, arrTeam , &ifHome);

      if(ifHome == "true"){
         arrTeam[posHome] = home;
         arrGoalDiff[posHome] = homeGoalDiff;
      }
      else{
          arrGoalDiff[posHome] += homeGoalDiff;
      }


      posAway = searchAway(away, arrTeam , &ifAway);

      if(ifAway == "true"){
        arrTeam[posAway] = away;
        arrGoalDiff[posAway] = awayGoalDiff;
      }
      else{
          arrGoalDiff[posAway] += awayGoalDiff;
      }

      if(homeGoal > awayGoal){
          arrGoal[posHome] += 3;
      }
      else if(homeGoal == awayGoal){
          arrGoal[posHome] += 1;
          arrGoal[posAway] += 1;
      }
      else
          arrGoal[posAway] += 3;




      //cout << " checking teams: "<< arrTeam[posHome] << " " << arrTeam[posAway]<< endl;
      //cout << " Checking goals: "<< arrGoal[posHome] << " "<< arrGoal[posAway] << endl ;



      matches--;
      if (matches == 0) {
        //for(int a = 0; a <= 3; a++)
            //cout << arrGoal[a] << " "<< arrGoalDiff[a] << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {


          if (arrGoal[i] > arrGoal[i + 1]) {
            swap(arrGoal[i], arrGoal[i + 1]);
            swap(arrTeam[i], arrTeam[i + 1]);
            swap(arrGoalDiff[i], arrGoalDiff[i + 1]);
          } else if (arrGoal[i] == arrGoal[i + 1]) {

            if (arrGoalDiff[i] > arrGoalDiff[i + 1]) {
              swap(arrGoal[i], arrGoal[i + 1]);
              swap(arrTeam[i], arrTeam[i + 1]);
              swap(arrGoalDiff[i], arrGoalDiff[i + 1]);
            }
          }
        }
        int init = 2;
        cout <<endl << arrTeam[init+1] << " " << arrTeam[init];
      }
    }
    //cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    tcs--;
    memset(arrTeam, 0, sizeof(arrTeam));
    memset(arrGoal, 0, sizeof(arrGoal));
    memset(arrGoalDiff, 0, sizeof(arrGoalDiff));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Think about how many iterations you're doing in the `matches` loop. (Since the number of matches is fixed, use a for-loop. Do the summary outside the loop.)

Comment: @molbdnilo still the same output as before

Comment: Still, after changing *what*? Did you remove the thirteenth iteration?

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: @TobySpeight please explain in normal language i did'nt understood what you said

Comment: You have much more code than is necessary.  Please reduce it to a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem, without all the irrelevant stuff.